# Prove limit of a monotonic sequence using partial limit

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
Let a be a partial limit of a monotonic sequence $a_n$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$

**What I did:**
Let $a_{n_k}$ be a sub sequence that converges to a (we know it exists since a is a partial limit). By hypothesis we assume that exists $a_{n_l} \to b, b > a$. Therefore from monotonic exists $a_{n_0} \in a_{n_l}$ s.t $a<a_{n_0}<b$. This is not possible because then $a_{n_k}$ would be finite (which we know it isn't from the definition of a sequence).
(similar proof for b < a). Therefore a=b.

Does this proof suffice?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you did proves that $a$ is the only possible candidate for $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n$. Since you have proved that $a_n \le a$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, a call to the [Monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) suffices to conclude.